How to have PyCharm show multiple plots at once, like spyder?
I am using pycharm, and importing numpy and matplotlib. With the same code, in spyder there is a "plots" section, that shows all of the plots generated after clicking run, I can switch between them with ease. As for pycharm, instead after running the program, I am presented with a pop up window, I can only see the next plot by closing the current window, and I can't go back. The code also runs all at once in Spyder, but in pycharm, the code runs as the windows are closed.
Spyder Plots Window
Python Plot Window
I've tried going into the setting's but haven't found anything, which makes me wonder if it has to do with matplotlib or numpy, but that wouldn't make sense as the code is the same in the two programs, so it's got to be in the program settings.

When you say show multiple plots, do you mean show them all in one window, or do you want them in separate windows?

You can use the command ".add_subplot" to add something to your subplot - for example say you want to have multiple subplots shown together, you can do something like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

After doing so, you can then plot on either axis separately, such as
ax1.plot([X_axis_data], [Y_axis_data])
ax2.plot([X_axis_data], [Y_axis_data])

you can then label your axis for them separately in the normal way of using things like:
ax1.set_xlabel(x_title)
ax2.set_xlabel(x_title2)

this will make it so that you can easily see both graphs at the same time after doing plt.show
(more information at https://pieriantraining.com/tutorial-how-to-have-multiple-plots-on-same-figure-in-matplotlib/)

What I think you are looking for is to use python native to plot, and not the built in pycharm plot window.  Go into settings and type "plots" in the search bar, then uncheck "Show plots in tool window".

